# $\lim_{p \to \infty}{\rho_p(x,y)}$, where $\rho_p$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

I need to prove that for $\rho_p(x,y):=(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

$\lim_{p \to \infty}{\rho_p(x,y)} = \max_{1\le i\le n}|x_i-y_i|$

Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Show that 
$$\max_{i=1,...,n}\{|x_i-y_i|\} \leq \rho_p(x,y)\leq n^{1/p}\max_{i=1,...,n}\{|x_i-y_i|\}$$